# Tomcat Remote Address filter doesn't work

Tags: apache, tomcat, web.xml, restrict

I seem to have a problem which it seems easy but i can't find a solution , although similar threads are opened hear.
Well , i want to deny access to a  url which contains a pdf:
attica.unipi.gr:8080/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/5/a3iologisi%20genika.pdf?sequence=1

Keep in mind that this is not a solid url but this part of it -->           /123456789/5/a3iologisi%20genika.pdf?sequence=1 , is generated dynamically ,depending on which pdf the user clicks to see.

So , based on this :
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter , i tried this:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>deny</param-name>
    <param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/xmlui/bitstream/handle/*/*/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But still dosen't work.I believe that this is a url-pattern issue so i tried changing the pattern as

```
/xmlui/bitstream/handle/*/*/*pdf
```

or

```
/attica.unipi.gr:8080/xmlui/bitstream/handle/*/*/*
```

But still no luck.
It either restricts access to the whole site or does nothing at all.

Any suggestions?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the Servlet specification for what constitutes a valid URL pattern. The short version is that they either need to end in a wild card (e.g. `<url-pattern>/foo/bar/*</url-pattern>` ) or start with one (`<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>`)

If all you want to do is match any file with a pdf extexnsion then `<url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>` is what you need. Tomcat (or any other Servlet container) will ignore the query parameters when doing the URL pattern matching.

As an aside, neither the protocol, host name, port nor context path should appear in the URL pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I also tried the extension pattern <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern> but still nothing happened..